# What does the phrase 'driving power' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this following context, what does the phrase 'driving power' mean?

Does it mean 'force' or momentum'?

Does the word 'direct' use with the phrase 'driving forec' as modifier?

Context:

> For example, if a man, being filled with greed or anger, is induced by
> his infatuation and delusive thoughts to commit various crimes, such
> as murder, theft, adultery, etc., in that case avijjå is the direct
> inducement and driving power for the subsequent arising of all those
> bad manifestations of will, i.e. of all those unwholesome
> kamma-formations.

Source:
Fundamentals of Buddhism
Four Lectures
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: _Direct_ modifies _inducement, driving_ modifies _power_.

Comment: I think it's a poor translation (a *lot* of the phrasing is non-idiomatic). It should be ***driving force***. The important point is that text is not a good source if you're trying to learn English.

Answer (score 1):

"Driving power" refers to the force to push something forward.

This can be a literal, physical manifestation such as the horsepower of a car engine, or the power behind an electric tool, or it can be metaphorical like in the example you have given.

The term "Driving force," is also common, and means the same thing. which sounds more natural may be a regional thing.